# Getting image path through a torchvision dataloader using local images

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I want to use a dataloader in my script.

normaly the default function call would be like this.

```
dataset = ImageFolderWithPaths(
    data_dir,
    transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ColorJitter(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
            transforms.Resize((img_size_XY, img_size_XY)),
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(_mean , _std)
        ])
)

dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=False,
    num_workers=2
)
```

and to iterate through this dataloader i use

```
for inputs, labels , paths in _dataloader:
    break
```

now i need to collect the path for each image.

i found in github this code: (https://gist.github.com/andrewjong/6b02ff237533b3b2c554701fb53d5c4d)

```
class ImageFolderWithPaths(datasets.ImageFolder):
    """Custom dataset that includes image file paths. Extends
    torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder
    """

    # override the __getitem__ method. this is the method that dataloader calls
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # this is what ImageFolder normally returns 
        original_tuple = super(ImageFolderWithPaths, self).__getitem__(index)
        # the image file path
        path = self.imgs[index][0]
        # make a new tuple that includes original and the path
        tuple_with_path = (original_tuple + (path,))
        return tuple_with_path

# EXAMPLE USAGE:
# instantiate the dataset and dataloader
data_dir = "your/data_dir/here"
dataset = ImageFolderWithPaths(data_dir) # our custom dataset
dataloader = torch.utils.DataLoader(dataset)

# iterate over data
for inputs, labels, paths in dataloader:
    # use the above variables freely
    print(inputs, labels, paths)
```

But this code does not take transforms into account, like in my original code.

Can anybody help in how I should go about making it work with that?

Comment: Could you check what `dataset.transform` returns?

Comment: `StandardTransform
Transform: Compose(
               ColorJitter(brightness=[0.9, 1.1], contrast=[0.9, 1.1], saturation=[0.9, 1.1], hue=[-0.1, 0.1])
               Resize(size=(384, 384), interpolation=bilinear, max_size=None, antialias=None)
               ToTensor()
               Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
           )`

Comment: And you are not getting any errors when calling an instance from the dataset?

Comment: with the initial code it works like it should. When i add the code from github it doesent work but i suppose its due to the missing trasforms which means that the images do not get resized. ( or the github code doesent work, but according to the comments it does)

Comment: The code with the example in github worked with you? I tried it but I have some issues.

Comment: no thats what i am saying that it didnt work. But i dont know if it is my implementation faulty or if just the algorithm is broken

Comment: I solved the problem and I will post the answer now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `ImageFolderWithPaths` inherits from `datasets.ImageFolder` as shown in the code from GitHub and `datasets.ImageFolder` has the following arguments including transform: (see [here](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html#torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder) for more info)

> torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root: str, transform:
> Optional[Callable] = None, target_transform: Optional[Callable] =
> None, loader: Callable[[str], Any] = ,
> is_valid_file: Optional[Callable[[str], bool]] = None)

*Solution: you can use your transformations directly when you instantiate `ImageFolderWithPaths`.*

```
import torch
from torchvision import datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader 

class ImageFolderWithPaths(datasets.ImageFolder):

    def __getitem__(self, index):
  
        img, label = super(ImageFolderWithPaths, self).__getitem__(index)
        
        path = self.imgs[index][0]
        
        return (img, label ,path)


# put here your root directory not subfolders directory
# subfolders should be names of classes or encodings
root_dir = "training" 

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((32, 32)), 
                                transforms.ToTensor()]) # my transformations.

dataset = ImageFolderWithPaths(root_dir,transform=transform) # add transformation directly

dataloader = DataLoader(dataset)


for inputs, labels, paths in dataloader:
    print(inputs.shape, labels, paths)

# output
torch.Size([1, 3, 32, 32]) tensor([0]) ('training\\0\\1.jpg',)
torch.Size([1, 3, 32, 32]) tensor([0]) ('training\\0\\1000.jpg',)
torch.Size([1, 3, 32, 32]) tensor([0]) ('training\\0\\10005.jpg',)
torch.Size([1, 3, 32, 32]) tensor([0]) ('training\\0\\10010.jpg',)
```

I also edited the code from github because there is no `torch.utils.DataLoader` but `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.